# Errors when loading terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

Every time I run a new terminal window (before I do a single thing), I am greeted with these messages:

```
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
-bash: grep: command not found
-bash: tar: command not found
-bash: cat: command not found
```

For instance, when I type `cd ~/`, I get: `-bash: find: command not found`.

Can anyone help?  I don't know where to start.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your $PATH environment variable is screwed or has been reset. You'll have to find out where it is being set (or appended to). When you login, the system runs /etc/profile and then ~/.bash_profile (depending on your shell). Make sure $PATH is set correctly then make sure that grep/tar/cat are actually in your path.

Comment: i had a $PATH line in my `.bash_profile` which i deleted and now everything worked as before.  i'll do more research, but should i reset $PATH somewhere now?

Comment: Usually, when you set PATH, you do it incrementally.  That is, the new value is set with something like: `export PATH=$NEWBINDIR:$PATH` or `export PATH=$PATH:$NEWBINDIR`.  You can get more complicated; I use a script which weeds out duplicate entries from a PATH so it stays short.  But you should keep `/bin` and `/usr/bin` on the PATH at a minimum, unless you have an extremely good reason to change that setting (such as `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`, as on Solaris; then you only need one of the two entries).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is something wrong with your profile (`~/.profile`).
Check the content of `~/.bashrc`
and also `/etc/profile`

It seems there's something wrong in these files; it looks like PATH is either missing or malformed.

PATH should contain  both `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, usually set in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: We can debate the relative wisdom of the colon at the start of PATH; that means that commands in the current directory are executed in preference to those in the system directories.  The colon at the end means that the current directory is also at the end of the PATH.

Comment: sorry, maybe I was not clear enough with the colons I've meant those 2 directories should be there. the PATH should not start and end with colons, however there should be a colons in place to separate directories. It's not that easy to diagnose this without seeing the contents of the profile, however it looks like that there is something set up in the profile for PS1 which cannot run as it's not in PATH

Comment: It's odd that the commands listed are things like `tar` and `find`.  It's not so uncommon to use `grep` or `cat` or `env`.  I agree with your assessment; so does the accepted answer.